# Validating Various Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

True or false?

```
3 ∈ {1, 2, 3} : True
{2} ∈ {1, 2}  : False
{3} ∈ {{1}, {2}, {3}}  : True
1 ∈ {1}  : True
1 ∈ {{1}, 2}  : False
1 ⊂ {1}        :False
{1} ⊂ {1, 2}   : True
{1} ⊂ {1. {2}}  : True
```

These are my answers, but I have no way of knowing if they are correct or not. Could someone verify that they are?

Comment: It all looks good to me.

Comment: They are correct, assuming the period in the final statement is meant to be a comma.  It would benefit you to visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to type in MathJax and $\LaTeX$ to make your equations easier to read.  $\{2\}\not\in\{1,2\}$ and $\{1\}\subseteq\{1,\{2\}\}$ for example.

Comment: They look fine to me.